# Accessing Marketing Cloud 'Active Salesforce Sends' through SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api

Hi I need to get a feed of all scheduled sends within MC. This isn't an issue for most email sends. However, for any scheduled Salesforce Sends they don't appear in the SentEvent object.

The below code gets all SentEvents based on the `SendID (JobID)`:

```
%%[    
SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")  
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "SentEvent")   
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","SendID")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","EventDate")  
SET @tsd = InvokeRetrieve(@rr)  
]%%
```

Any idea on how to return any Active Salesforce Sends that don't have a JobId and only have an Id? e.g. for the following scheduled send?

> ID: 33
>  Definition Name:
> GuidedSend_8dffde-f1fb-404f-9bc5-sdfsdf
>  Status: Scheduled
> Created: 11/05/2018 10:15 AM
>  Scheduled: 14/05/2018 11:00 AM
> SyncId:
>  JobId:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the soap object send? (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send.htm)