# Programatically access/notify on Failed Salesforce Send Emails from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

My organization has had some problems in Marketing Cloud with scheduled Salesforce Send Emails failing (due to issues such as Sales Cloud reports used as audiences timing out). While we're working to address the root causes, for peace of mind we'd also like to implement notification for when a scheduled send fails. However I haven't been able to figure out how to programmatically check for failed Salesforce Sends.

So far I have tried 1) querying the [Job data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5) (nothing I can see indicates failures: JobStatus for a failed send is just "New," SalesForceErrorSubscriberCount is 0, and failed sends actually have a DeliveredTime), and 2) doing a "Not Sent" data extract (data for failed sends doesn't seem to be there). Also per the previous unanswered question [Accessing Marketing Cloud 'Active Salesforce Sends' through SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/accessing-marketing-cloud-active-salesforce-sends-through-soap-api) and backed by some quick testing just now, it does not look like Salesforce Sends are accessible via the SentEvent API object.

Can anyone provide guidance--how can I get at this information, aside from manually checking for failures in Marketing Cloud's *Salesforce Send Emails > View Active Sends* UI?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? If yes, could you include some information?

Comment: Sadly I never did find a direct solution, and we've been moving away from Salesforce sends. However I noticed that in the latest (July 2020) release of MC, an "Alert Manager" has been added, which will email a (single) designated user upon a failed send (see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_july_2020_alert_manager.htm&type=5). We've enabled that but I don't know yet whether it will work for Salesforce sends specifically.